# replace a text inside a block of code in apache2.conf file using sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have been playing with some tricks of useful sed command in linux to replace a word of text inside a block of code in apache2.conf file. Tried searching for already answered solutions on google and stackoverflow. But, those couldn't really get help.

Here is the piece of code in apache2.conf file.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

i want the the word denied inside the block to be chnanged to granted. Like below,

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm trying with the command

```
sudo sed -i "/<IfModule "^\.ht">/,\@</IfModule>@ s/Require all denied/Require all granted/" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and i am sure i am somewhere wrong at the the double quotes used inside the opening tag .

any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/<FilesMatch "\^\\\.ht">/{f=1} f{sub(/denied/,"granted")} /<\/FilesMatch>/{f=0} 1' file
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

The above just sets a flag when the start line is found, clears it when the end line is found, and changes denied to granted when that flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/<FilesMatch "^\\.ht">/,\@</FilesMatch>@ s/Require all denied/Require all granted/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```